# C++ : difference of execution time between two call of a virtual function

Tags: c++, performance, function, virtual, c++11

Consider this code under **gcc 4.5.1 (Ubuntu 10.04, intel core2duo 3.0 Ghz)** 
It's just 2 tests, in the first one I make a direct call on virtual fucnion and in the second I call it via a Wrapper class :

*test.cpp*

```cpp
#define ITER 100000000

class Print{

public:

typedef Print* Ptr;

virtual void print(int p1, float p2, float p3, float p4){/*DOES NOTHING */}

};

class PrintWrapper
{

    public:

      typedef PrintWrapper* Ptr;

      PrintWrapper(Print::Ptr print, int p1, float p2, float p3, float p4) :
      m_print(print), _p1(p1),_p2(p2),_p3(p3),_p4(p4){}

      ~PrintWrapper(){}

      void execute()
      { 
        m_print->print(_p1,_p2,_p3,_p4); 
      }

    private:

      Print::Ptr m_print;
      int _p1;
      float _p2,_p3,_p4;

};

 Print::Ptr p = new Print();
 PrintWrapper::Ptr pw = new PrintWrapper(p, 1, 2.f,3.0f,4.0f);

void test1()
{

 //-------------test 1-------------------------

 for (auto var = 0; var < ITER; ++var) 
 {
   p->print(1, 2.f,3.0f,4.0f);
 }

 }

 void test2()
 {

  //-------------test 2-------------------------

 for (auto var = 0; var < ITER; ++var) 
 {
   pw->execute();
 }

}

int main() 
{ 
  test1(); 
  test2();
}
```

I profiled it with gprof and objdump :

```cpp
g++ -c -std=c++0x -pg -g -O2 test.cpp
objdump -d -M intel -S test.o > objdump.txt
g++ -pg test.o -o test
./test
gprof test > gprof.output
```

in gprof.output I observed that test2() takes more time than test1() but I can't explain it

```cpp
Each sample counts as 0.01 seconds.
  %   cumulative   self              self     total           
 time   seconds   seconds    calls  ms/call  ms/call  name    
 49.40      0.41     0.41        1   410.00   540.00  test2()
 31.33      0.67     0.26 200000000     0.00     0.00  Print::print(int, float, float, float)
 19.28      0.83     0.16        1   160.00   290.00  test1()
  0.00      0.83     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  global constructors keyed to p
```

The assembly code in objdump.txt doesn't help me either :

```cpp
 //-------------test 1-------------------------
 for (auto var = 0; var < ITER; ++var) 
  15:   83 c3 01                add    ebx,0x1
 {
   p->print(1, 2.f,3.0f,4.0f);
  18:   8b 10                   mov    edx,DWORD PTR [eax]
  1a:   c7 44 24 10 00 00 80    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x10],0x40800000
  21:   40 
  22:   c7 44 24 0c 00 00 40    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0xc],0x40400000
  29:   40 
  2a:   c7 44 24 08 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x8],0x40000000
  31:   40 
  32:   c7 44 24 04 01 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x4],0x1
  39:   00 
  3a:   89 04 24                mov    DWORD PTR [esp],eax
  3d:   ff 12                   call   DWORD PTR [edx]

  //-------------test 2-------------------------
 for (auto var = 0; var < ITER; ++var) 
  65:   83 c3 01                add    ebx,0x1

      ~PrintWrapper(){}

      void execute()
      { 
        m_print->print(_p1,_p2,_p3,_p4); 
  68:   8b 10                   mov    edx,DWORD PTR [eax]
  6a:   8b 70 10                mov    esi,DWORD PTR [eax+0x10]
  6d:   8b 0a                   mov    ecx,DWORD PTR [edx]
  6f:   89 74 24 10             mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x10],esi
  73:   8b 70 0c                mov    esi,DWORD PTR [eax+0xc]
  76:   89 74 24 0c             mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0xc],esi
  7a:   8b 70 08                mov    esi,DWORD PTR [eax+0x8]
  7d:   89 74 24 08             mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x8],esi
  81:   8b 40 04                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [eax+0x4]
  84:   89 14 24                mov    DWORD PTR [esp],edx
  87:   89 44 24 04             mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x4],eax
  8b:   ff 11                   call   DWORD PTR [ecx]
```

How can we explain such a difference ?

Comment: To do performance measuring and get sensible results you should compile with the highest optimisation level (-O3). Without actually analysing the assembly, my guess is that the wrapper is inlined but the pointer is accessed via an extra level of indirection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `test2()`, the program must first load `pw` from the heap, then call `pw->execute()` (which incurs call overhead), then load `pw->m_print` as well as the `_p1` through `_p4` arguments, then load the vtable pointer for `pw`, then load the vtable slot for `pw->Print`, then call `pw->Print`. Because the compiler can't see through the virtual call, it then must assume all of these values have changed for the next iteration, and reload them all.

In `test()`, the arguments are inline in the code segment, and we only have to load `p`, the vtable pointer, and the vtable slot. We've saved five loads this way. This could easily account for the time difference.

In short - the loads of `pw->m_print` and `pw->_p1` through `pw->_p4` are the culprit here.

Comment: @bdonian so m_print, p1 and p4 are reloaded at each iteration ?? would explain a lot... Is there anything I can do about it ?

Comment: m_print, _p1, _p2, _p3, and _p4 are all reloaded. Saving them to locals at the level of the for loop would let you avoid this overhead, although obviously this requires breaking encapsulation. Alternately, if inlining is possible, then making pw local (or copying it to a local) may be enough.

Answer (score 2):

One difference is that the values you're passing into print in test1 are going to be stored in the instructions themselves, whereas the stuff in PrintWrapper have to be loaded from the heap.  You can see this going on in the assembler.  Could be running into different memory access times for that reason.

Answer (score 1):

In the direct call, the compiler can optimize away the virtuality of the function because the type of `p` is known at compile time (because the only assignment to `p` is visible). In `PrintWrapper`, the type is erased and the virtual function call must be performed.

Comment: While e assignment to the pointer is visible, unless the compiler performs whole program optimisation (gcc -O2 doesn't) it cannot assume that from the assignment to the call the **global** variable will not be reset.

Answer (score 1):

Are you actually printing, or just calling a function called Print that does nothing?
If you're actually printing, you're weighing the hair on the hog.

Regardless, gprof is blind to I/O, so it's only looking at your CPU usage.

Notice, Test2 does 11 moves before the call, while Test1 does only 6.
So if more PC samples land in Test2, that's not surprising.

Comment: the function actually does nothing;

Comment: @codablank1: Right, so just look at how many instructions it has to execute in the loop.